# I created a JIRA issue. How can I add it to an existing JIRA Rapid Board?

Tags: jira

Example of a JIRA Rapid Board:

[image]

I created a JIRA issue via Issue -> Create. How can I add the newly created issue to that Rapid Board? I'd like to add the issue in the "TO DO" column of the board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer](https://redd.it/1axin3d) from Reddit user [lunagra80](https://www.reddit.com/user/lunagra80):

> Boards are just pretty UIs on top of a filter. If tickets don't match the filter they can't be seen in the boards
>
> For example if the filter has the JQL "project= ABC" and you created the issue in project XYZ then the issue will not be visualized in your board, same if your filter has "field A = 123" but the field in the issue is empty or has a different value

To view the filters:

> Go to the top right menu Board > Config Check in the General page if the filter includes the project you have created the issue into, or if the issue you have created matches the filter.
>
> If this is correct it means you haven't mapped the columns in your board to the actual statuses in the workflow of that project. In the same Config page you can select the Column option in the menu there and drag and drop the.statuses under the column you want to map them to. When you go back to the board you will see the issue in the related column
>
> If this is wrong, then either you have created the issue under the wrong project or the issue is missing a value in a field that matches the filter

That worked me. I was able to add a JIRA issue an existing JIRA Rapid Board by setting a field in the JIRA issue to match the  JIRA Rapid Board filters.

Screenshot of the top right menu Board > Config Check in the General page:

[image]

The filters can be seen here:

[image]